# Summarize value from a series based on condition(s)

Tags: excel, sum, formula, addition, sumifs

Currently I have an Excel-file where I track my wins/losses from betting with a friend. The bets are placed be either of us as you can see in Column K

I need help with developing a formula (Assuming it will be an SUMIFS) where it will calculate the running total for each person (Farzam & Leon). The idea is that you can see how much profit you are in total after each game. I need to code to work correctly since I will be creating a graph based on this data.

So the idea would be something like this: Code checks if Bet is placed by Farzam or Leon. Then it will add the value for the M-Column (M9 is the first one). Then the code needs to take this value and add it based on the previous value that was won/lost by Farzam or Leon.

You'll need to write code for two columns (Y and Z). Should be fairly equivalent.

[image]

Enclosed you'll find a screenshot of the document so you get an better idea.
Let me know if anything is unclear and I'll try to explain better.

Currently I have the following code, but it's not working like my description.
=SUMIFS($M9:M16;K9:K16;"Leon")

Comment: *You'll need to write code for two columns (Y and Z)* I'm sorry, but this is not what we do here. We are here to help out with your attempts, and help you sort any problems you encounter. But we are not a free coding service. In your case I suggest starting with the `Sumif(` formula.

Comment: I do get that, if you'd like to see what I've written I can show you that (although it's not close to be working like I want it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a running total, meaning only to sum the range from this line backwards, and account for whom has made this bet.

[image]

In this case, the following formula can be used:

```
=SUMIF($M$9:$M9,"Leon",$K$9:$K9)
```

Note the $ signs meaning these are static values. When dragged down with the fill handle, the formula will start counting up the range `$M$9:$M10` then 11, 12 etc.` and only calculate from that line backwards. This results in the above running total picture.

The way you did it:

```
=SUMIFS($M9:M16;K9:K16;"Leon")
```

Is close, but will only calculate the entire range at once, so always have one static output of the complete total.

Comment: I Understand you explanation, thank you!
However I just get 0 as output.
https://gyazo.com/6533024b6fd247840388826d3080625f

Edit: I needed to swap M and L in your forumla

Comment: You might want to check if the ranges in the formula are correct, the first should reference column "Betplacer" and the second "Win/Loss". Also, check if the "Win/Loss" range has calculable (currency) values, and not text.